# what is the logic of sql statement for get user by radians

Tags: mysql, math, geometry, sql

Please help me i don't understand what is 3959 in this query and what is the logic of this query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians("%s") ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) -    
radians("%s") ) + sin( radians("%s") ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Zips 
HAVING distance < "%s"
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is to find locations using latitudes and longitudes, Please refer to [Finding Locations with MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

This above logic uses [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to find location within a sphere

Answer (score 4):

3959 is Earth's radius in miles. The query is calculating the distance (in miles) between the entered longitude and latitude vs. the longitude and latitude of points in the table, and selecting the closest. There is not that much logic, it's pure math. Given that the distance itself isn't output, you could even leave off the multiplication by 3959 and still get the same result.